# UITableView and playing audio upon clicking a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, audio

I'm trying to find a simple solution to play a sound when a particular cell is tapped on a tableview. I have tried methods suggested in a few similar questions on here but they are more specific to certain projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Row selected");
    int selectedRow = indexPath.row;

   [self chooseAudioFile:selectedRow];
}

-(void)chooseAudioFile:(NSInteger)number{

       switch (number) {
            case 0:
                 audioFilename = @"audioFileName1.mp3";
                break;
            case 1:
                 audioFilename = @"audioFileName2.mp3";
                break;

             //and so on

              default:
              break;
        }
      [self playAudio];

}
-(void)playAudio{

//play audio using the audioFileName string

}
```